# Javascript search a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Having some issues with eval an array to return the 2nd value of the multidimensional array.

```
az1_array = new Array([33010,   50],[33012, 50],[33013, 50]);
nzone=33012;
eval(az1_array).forEach(function(t) {
     if(t[0]==nzone){
        alert(az1_array[t][1]);
    }
});
```

I am trying to get the 2nd argument when this code is run but it is always returning the first value 33010 no matter what i make nzone, how would i get it to search the entire array and only return the 2nd argument of nzone?

Comment: Why are you using eval?

Comment: What do you mean by "*[second] argument of `nzone`,*" - `nzone` is a number, it has no arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either keep most of your code the same, just change two things:

```
var az1_array = new Array([33010,   50],[33012, 51],[33013, 52]);
nzone=33012;
az1_array.forEach(function(t) { // remove eval (or clarify why you used it in the first place)
   if(t[0]==nzone){
      alert(t[1]); // change the alert
   }
});
```

Or use already existing methods liker `Array.prototype.filter()` [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1):

First, avoid usage of global variables. Next, `eval` is unnecessary, and you shouldn't use it for such things. Third, use `Array.filter` and filter what you want.

```
console.log(az1_array.filter(function(arr){
   return arr[0] == nzone;
}));
```

[**Why eval isn't suitable here:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21)

> `eval()` is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed
>   with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string
>   that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running
>   malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your
>   webpage / extension. More importantly, third party code can see the
>   scope in which `eval()` was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks
>   in ways to which the similar `Function` is not susceptible.

Also, it's pretty slow compared to the alternatives.